# How to make objects follow other objects?

Tags: game-engine

I've to make a cricket game in blender. How can I make the fielders follow the ball so that ball can be stopped?

Comment: This is not a question searching for a simple answer...  this is more a tutorial request...  you should perhaps better learn from game examples or tutorials. Anyway, eg: you can stop the ball in many ways, including collisions, game conditions, keyboard or mouse actions... To learn about players following the ball, you could find tutorials about making a camera follow the player's avatar movements in the scene: it could be something similar..

Comment: Although ball can be stopped by collision, how would the fielder know the direction in which to run to catch or stop it. Is there a way to find the trajectory of the ball after the batsman hits it?

Comment: You should track perhaps the ball position, not the direction...  but I'm no expert and as said this is quite difficult to answer... I guess a player is playing that game right..? So, it could be him to decide where to go....